# Git no me deja ver el codigo

Tags: git, gitlab

Buen Dia,
Estoy trabajando con gitlab, sucede que tengo dos proyectos, cree un solo repositorio y guarde los dos proyectos en el mismo repositorio pero al ver el codigo en git me aparece de la siguiente manera.

[image: Imagen tomada de gitlab]

como puedo acceder y ver el codigo de la que dice @ 84842d74

Gracias

Comment: He realizado una investigación y aparece que es general cuando se crea un proyecto dentro de un proyecto y aparece como un sub-proyecto, pero aun no he podido encontrar como extraerlo

Comment: probaste hacer un git pull (url donde esta alojado)?

Comment: ten en cuenta que eso no seria correcto. Tus proyectos deberian ser independientes. Otra cosa es que uno de los proyectos requiera el otro, en ese caso lo tratarias como una dependencia.